# Sorting array of objects in MUI cards depending on social media

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, grid

I'm working on an app that displays athlete data in a grid using MUI Grid. The colors on the left border are based on which social network is associated with that card.

[image: Webpage image]

What I want to do is have a column for each social network, one for facebook, one for instagram, and one for reddit. That way each column will have the same color cards.

I just cant seem to figure out how to go about doing this. the data from my API is already sorted by social network, but Mui is taking the data from my API and adding the cards row by row instead of column by column.

Here is my code for the athletes cards

```js
import React from 'react'
import { AthleteCardContainer, AthleteImage, AthleteDetailsContainer, TopContainer, BottomContainer, FBLogo, RedditLogo, InstaLogo, LinkIconLogo } from '../styles/athlete-styles'

export const AtheleteCard = ({athlete}) => {

    function numFormatter(num) {
        if(num > 999 && num < 1000000){
            return (num/1000).toFixed(1) + 'K';
        }else if(num > 1000000){
            return (num/1000000).toFixed(1) + 'M'; 
        }else if(num < 900){
            return num; 
        }
    }

  return (
    <AthleteCardContainer social={athlete.platform}>

        <AthleteImage src={athlete.profileImage}/>

        <AthleteDetailsContainer>
            <TopContainer>
            <h1>{athlete.name}</h1>
            <span>@{athlete.handle}</span>
            </TopContainer>
            <BottomContainer>
          
            <h3>{athlete.platform === "Instagram" ?  <InstaLogo/> : athlete.platform === "Facebook" ? <FBLogo/> : athlete.platform === "Reddit" ? <RedditLogo/> : null} {numFormatter(athlete.subscriberCount)}</h3>
            <a href={athlete.url}><p><LinkIconLogo/>{athlete.url}</p></a>
            </BottomContainer>
        </AthleteDetailsContainer>

    </AthleteCardContainer>
  )
}
```

and my code for the grid itself

```js
export const Athletes = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const athletes = useSelector(state => state.athleteReducer.athletes.athletes)
  

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.getAthletes());
  }, [])
  
  console.log(athletes, "from selector")

  return (
  <div>
    <Grid container >
    {athletes.map(athlete => (
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
      <AtheleteCard athlete={athlete}/>
    </Grid>
    ))}
    </Grid>
  </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you please show me the array

Comment: @MidoDevi Sure thing, here https://ibb.co/yPYXbqX 
12 items, the first 4 are insta, then facebook, then reddit

Comment: I need the actual response as a snippet here, not just a screenshot, so i can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<Box sx={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', display: flex}}>
    <Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      justifyContent="flex-start"
      alignItems="flex-start"
    >
```

To align items in columns.
Check if this works for you.
Remove div use Box and check if this works

Comment: @cody hayes : check if the above solution works for you. You can also refer https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/

Comment: That sort of worked, each card is one column but it doesn't wrap. It is in order like I need but it goes off the page instead of staying in the container. flex wrap doesn't seem to work either @Tanya maheshwari

Comment: @CodyHayes: can you post the code which you wrote and please create an example either in codesandbox so that I can help you out. It goes off the page instead of being in container can you please explain this?